# Linux Uart driver modification

Tags: linux, kernel, driver, uart

I want to modify my linux kernel's (2.6.32) UART driver.  I am using the standard uart driver for ttyS2 I dont know the exact files.  The problem is Simple, setting and keeping a gpio pin high during transmission and while receving it must be low.

Which files should i refer to ? And any ideas about bitbanging gpio s from uart driver are wellcome...

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

- Try to understand how the [Linux Serial Driver Layers](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6331) are working and organized .
- Determine which serial chip (driver) your device is using.
- Hack the bit-banging GPIO into the low-lever driver.

OR:

Maybe you can abuse another signal line instead of a GPIO. If you operate your UART in RS485 mode, mostly the RTS behaves like you want -> high during transmission. I'm not sure if the rest of the communication would be rs232-compliant, but why not just try.